# Pattern finding

Tags: pattern

As shown in the picture, find the correct option. Logical explanation is required
[image]

Answer (score 11):

Answer

> (B)

Because

> The top row shows the letters B, D and F with their reflections to their left; the next letter would be H (every other letter of the alphabet), which if we reflect in the same manner produces the image shown in (B).